# when should a function return in hapijs route call

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have two different examples, one from makemehapi(some sort of interactive lesson) and another from official hapi.js website. The 1st one looks like this -

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');    
var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: Number(process.argv[2] || 8080)
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('Hello hapi');
    }
});

server.start(function () {});
```

just look at server.route method that is being called. The handler has an anonymous function that calls `reply(...);` and doesn't returns. Now the hapijs website mentions the following call:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path:'/', 
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        return reply('hello world');
    }
});
```

Here I assume value of reply statement is returned and the rest of the example is same. So are these two methods same? calling return or not calling it dosen't makes a difference here (I've executed both) but would it matter in some other case? Maybe there are some form of middlewares into the equation too, and are they the reason we aren't calling return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hapi doesn't use the return value from your handler whatsoever (see from [the code](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/lib/handler.js#L96)). Your 2 samples are functionally equivalent.

### So why return?

Adding `return` when you call a callback (which is what the `reply()` interface is) is just a good practice that marks your intention for the function to stop execution at that point. It prevents anyone from adding code to execute after the line.

[From hapi style guide](http://hapijs.com/styleguide#callback):

> - Callbacks should always be called with explicit return

This might seem fairly pointless with the simple example but it's a good habit to get into. It might save your life in more complex scenarios, ensuring a callback is only called once and with the correct value.

See these two code samples to see what I mean:

#### WRONG!

```
const diffuseBomb = function (person, callback) {

    if (person === 'james bond') {
        callback('PHEW! We\'re saved!');
    }

    callback('BOOOM!');
};

diffuseBomb('james bond', (sound) => console.log(sound));
```

#### RIGHT!

```
const diffuseBomb = function (person, callback) {

    if (person === 'james bond') {
        return callback('PHEW! We\'re saved!');
    }

    return callback('BOOOM!');
};

diffuseBomb('james bond', (sound) => console.log(sound));
```